# How to fast scroll on Chrome Mobile

Tags: chrome-for-android

I just installed Chrome Mobile on my Galaxy Note (ICS, CM9) and while it has this nice card-like interface, I didn't find how to flick the screen to fast scroll to top or bottom of pages.

In other words, using the Android stock browser, when on a very long page, if I swipe the screen for up to down fast enough with one finger, the page will scroll very fast and continuously from the bottom of page to top of the page. How to do the same with Chrome Mobile?

Comment: Probably have to submit a feature request to the Chrome team

Answer (score 3):

The amount of scroll you get on a fling is based on the [friction assigned to that flick action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html#setFriction%28float%29).  In the stock browser the friction assigned to the vertical fling is really low.  So your fling isn't a command to get to the top / bottom of the page, there just isn't enough friction to stop you from getting there.  You can test this by finding an [insanely long page](http://www.worldslongestwebsite.com/) and giving it a good fling.  You'll go pretty far but you won't reach the bottom.  The Chrome Mobile application applies a bit more friction to the vertical fling, so that same mighty flick you got so much travel from in the stock browser won't get you quite as far in Chrome Mobile.

All that aside, it would probably be worthwhile to send a request via the help page that Google use the same friction coefficient on both apps for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

[UC Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl) or [Maxthon Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mx.browser) have the quick scroll/page down function.

Comment: A PlayStore link would be nice